# How to create crontab for Symfony command

Tags: php, symfony, cron

Currently, my application have several commands, and every time I have to type the command and run the program manually.

Currently, I am decided to create a crontab to execute those commands. But I am not sure the procedure for creating the crontab based on the Symfony. For example, how to create the crontab, which folder should I put the crontab file in, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find some [excellent references](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) from the Ubuntu Docs or from a [manual page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5) additionally a [nixcraft article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) can make sense of things, but all a crontab does is execute a shell command,

Each cron defintion gets on line of the file, formatted like so:

```
* * * * * command to be executed
- - - - -
| | | | |
| | | | ----- Day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
| | | ------- Month (1 - 12)
| | --------- Day of month (1 - 31)
| ----------- Hour (0 - 23)
------------- Minute (0 - 59)
```

The general form you'll probably want to take is:

```
0 12,13 * * * cd /var/www/path/to/symphonyappdir/ && php mysymphonything.php
```

the `cd` should generally use an absolute path to your app dir, the `&&` is logic for 'and', so if the 'cd' fails (presumably because the directory wasn't accessible) the second half wont execute.

Save this file anywhere, the [crontab manual](https://askubuntu.com/a/216711/250556) suggest that users should not directly edit crontab files.

Open your primary crontab file with:

```
crontab -e
```

Or add a new file to a crontab with:

```
crontab mynewcronfile
```

You can also get a current crontab file contense with:

```
crontab -l
```